# how to set item in DropDownList when DropDownList don't have item. in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to set item in DropDownList when DropDownList don't have item.

In asp.net simple code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>C#</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>VB</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>java</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = "php";
   if ( DropDownList1.Text == TextBox1.Text)
   {
       DropDownList1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
       TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
     }
}
```

Comment: How will you set the items if it doesn't exist in the dropdown? Do you want to add an item if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically add items to a dropdown?

Comment: Thanks. But i don't insert item to DropDownList..... I want if it doesn't exist show in ddl.. else show in TextBox....

Comment: So if the text in `TextBox1` matches an item that's in `DropDownList1`, you want to select that item, but if not, you want to copy the text into `TextBox2`?

Comment: @Tasan your question is not clear, can you clear what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks ... Ansari...
I want if TextBox1 = "php"... TextBox2 = "php"... if TextBox1 = "c#"... DropDownList1= "C#".... Now clear?

Comment: @Adam.... Yes i want that....

Comment: @Tasan try my answer now.

Comment: @Ansari... every time run if(item!=null)... else not run....
I want if textbox1 = "php" run textbox2 = "php" else textbox1 = "C#" run DropDownlist = "C#"...    Thanks for answer...

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to add that item and then have to select it like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "php";

    if (DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(TextBox1.Text) != null)    
    {
         DropDownList1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.
But i don't insert item to DropDownList.....
I want if it have show in ddl.. else show in TextBox....

Comment: Got it! I have updated the code. You can try it now!

Comment: Thanks Pawan Nogariya....
But this code error when TextBox1.Text = "C#", "VB" and "java"....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

This is your Dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>C#</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>VB</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>java</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This in your code behind

```
TextBox1.Text = "php";

    ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Text.ToUpper() == TextBox1.Text.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(item);
        TextBox2.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This code doesn't work....

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Tasan i modified my answer, Try this & make sure namespace `System.Linq;` is added.

Comment: @Tasan if it helps you can accept my answer by selecting tick icon, it will help other user who will visit this page